# Bucket Search & Dynamic queries

Tags: search, range, xquery, marklogic

MarkLogic 9.0.8.2

In database, we have data like this

```
<xmldata>
     <data>
         <name>name1</name>
         <value>E012M9876</value>
    <data>
    <data>
         <name>name2<name>
         <value>E015M6789</value>
    </data>
     <data>
         <name>name3</name>
         <value>E012M9876</value>
    <data>
    <data>
         <name>name1<name>
         <value>E015M6789</value>
    </data>
</xmldata>
```

User can search for any operator like "=, <, <=, >=, Between" & data are dynamics, so we can't create fixed buckets, queries can be like this

- name1:>=E011M1234 AND name1:<=E015M8921 (will return 2 records)
- name1:>E014M8769 (will return 1 record)
- name1:<=E013M7659 (will return 1 record)
- name2:=E015M6789 (will return 1 record)

I looked at across to find the dynamic bucket implementation in xQuery, but didn't found any.
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/search#id_69918

So can you please help on how to write code to implement this scenario?

If storing data in attributes instead of in elements, will be better approach, we can also do that.

```
<data>
    <value name="name1">E015M6789</value>
</data>
```

Comment: Are you trying to figure out how to construct a computed bucket https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/appendixa#id_91755 or are having trouble figuring out how to apply it in the options for a search https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/search-api#id_22725?

Comment: Thanks Mads Hansen for your reply, Sorry for late reply, in this case, its all depend on what user puts the data, so we can't get fixed values for bucket, so we want it to run like we put data in constraints with range options, so what is the best way to handle it?

Comment: And it's not an option to make elements with the name? i.e. `<name1>E015M6789</name>` and `<name2>E015M6789</name2>`? Even if you want to preserve the original data, you could implement the envelope pattern https://www.marklogic.com/blog/envelope-design-pattern/

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem is to create a TDE that indexes one row per data element with one column each for the name and value.

Then, an SQL or Optic query can match the appropriate rows based on boolean expressions on the value column.

Hoping that helps,